# Can SQL Server Report Services Designer be rehosted?

Tags: reporting-services, workflow-foundation

I would like to be able to edit and create at run time reports based on SQL Server Reporting Services from my application. Can SQL Server Report Services Designer control be rehosted in a custom .Net application outside Visual Studio, in a similar manner to how the WF workflow designer does? Is there any code sample for this?

Comment: Are you looking for the functionality found in Report Builder (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207032.aspx), or something more? There are ways to launch report builder 2.0 as a clickonce application, not sure about 3.0.

Comment: Yes I believe this will do it. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds good, added an answer and updated with a link that can be used to launch ClickOnce version of report builder 2.0 from the report server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Report Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207032.aspx) for designing reports outside of Business Intelligence Development Studio. If you want to launch report builder from a hyperlink, make sure at least SQL Server 2008 SP1 is installed on the report server and use this URL:

```
http://<servername>/reportserver/reportbuilder/ReportBuilder_2_0_0_0.application
```